# Why does the following jQuery function fire twice?

Tags: jquery

I have the following in my (document).ready function:

```
replace_fav_url();
```

and the jQuery function:

```
function replace_fav_url(){
    $j('a.fav').click(function(e) {
        $j.post($j(this).attr('href'));
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Everything works good with the exception that function seems to be called twice? 1 click two function calls?   Not sure what is going on here?

EDIT:

FULL application.js file:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

//Append javascritp header requests
$j.ajaxSetup({ 
  'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")}
});


$j(document).ready(function() {

    $j(document).ajaxSend(function(event, request, settings) {
    if (settings.type == 'GET') return;
    if (typeof(AUTH_TOKEN) == "undefined") return;
    settings.data = settings.data || "";
    settings.data += (settings.data ? "&" : "") + "authenticity_token=" + encodeURIComponent(AUTH_TOKEN);
  });


    replace_vote_urls();
    replace_fav_url();
});


function replace_vote_urls(){
    $j('a.vote').click(function(e) {
        $j.post($j(this).attr('href'));
        e.preventDefault();
    });

} 


function replace_fav_url(){
    $j('a.fav').click(function(e) {
        $j.post($j(this).attr('href'));
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Comment: can you please post the rest of your JS as well

Comment: added the full .js file FYI, (both functions [replace_vote_urls, replace_fav_url] fire twice.

Comment: Why not add a `debugger;` statement (hardcoded breakpoint) and use firebug's stack display to find out from where the function is called the second time?

Comment: I may not be related but I can see an issue in your code, your document.ready is missing a semicolon (;) in the end.

Comment: Just a side comment, if using jQuery, there is no need to normalize the event using `var ev = e || event;` since jQuery already normalizes things: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Comment: @user452830 added semicolon(s), @Peter removed normalization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm only guessing this is the problem, but if you call the `replace_fav_url()` function more than once, it will bind an additional click event to `a.fav`. And will continue to do so each time you call it.

If you change the number of `a.fav` elements in any way, it would be better to use `delegate()` or `live()` to bind a click event.

Comment: +1 for fudgey's answer. To demonstrate, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UGsHR/14/). Maybe you're calling `replace_fav_url()` somewhere else as well?

Comment: I've searched the entier project... only call each function once. I literally just wrote it so, its was unlikely that that that function call would be duplicated.... good suggestion though.  and that fiddle app is pretty slick.

Comment: Found it!  In rails adding -> :defaults will load your application.js file, then if you specifically add application.js again, you'll get the entier file 2x, giving you two calls for each action.